# Laravel Eloquent DB::Raw query does not allow WHERE statement and subquery together

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

The following query runs just fine when I paste it into my SQL tool, but through Laravel, it returns zero rows.

```
$sql = "
SELECT main_query.* FROM (
    SELECT
        c.id,
        c.name,
        c.order,
        cd.case,
        (SELECT count(*) from logs cl
            where
            c.id = cl.id
            and cl.status = 'OPEN'
        ) as cl_count,
        sdsc.task
    FROM `table` c
    INNER JOIN `table2` cd ON (c.id = cd.id)
    LEFT JOIN `table3` sdsc ON (c.id = sdsc.id)
    WHERE
        c.status = 'NEW'
    GROUP BY c.id
    ORDER BY cd.updated_at DESC                    
) main_query                
where main_query.cl_count > 1
GROUP BY main_query.id
ORDER BY main_query.updated_at DESC
limit 0,20
";
```

Due to the complexity of the actual query, I cannot convert it wholly into an eloquent query, so I am executing it using `DB::select(DB::raw($searchQuery));`

If I remove `where main_query.cl_count > 1`, the query runs just fine. What is causing this to fail, and how do I rewrite the code?

Comment: a sql dump might be helpful for people testing solutions.

Comment: on a side note you don't need `DB::raw` as `DB::select` is already a raw query (not Query Builder)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, generated by https://sql2builder.github.io/

```
DB::query()->fromSub(function ($query) {
    $query->from('table')
        ->select('table.id', 'table.name', 'table.order', 'table2.case', 'table3.task')
        ->on(function ($query) {
            $query->where('table.id','=','table2.id');
        })
        ->on(function ($query) {
            $query->where('table.id','=','table3.id');
        })
        ->where('table.status','=','NEW')
        ->groupBy('table.id')
        ->orderBy('','desc');
},'main_query')
->select('main_query.*')
->where('main_query.cl_count','>',1)
->groupBy('main_query.id')
->orderBy('','desc')
->get();
```